# How to compare to datetime values to millisecond accuracy in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql

I'm running a fairly straight forward LINQ query that looks like the following:

```
List<Event> lstEvents = db.Events.Where(e => e.SystemDatetime <= eventItem.SystemDatetime).ToList();
```

The SystemDateTime is a DateTime column in the database that stores datetimes in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss.fff. DateTime comparisons only compare to the nearest second which isn't accurate enough.

How do I compare the two values in the LINQ statement to the millisecond?

Comment: int diff =  date2.Subtract(date1).Milliseconds;

Comment: Is this Entity Framework? In C# and therefore LINQ-to-Objects DateTime comparisons are not done "to the nearest second" but by tick, i.e. with 100 nanosecond precision.

Comment: Most likely the accepted answer loads the whole list into memory before filtering it or will return the same result you're encountering. You have to change your data type of your column. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the total Milliseconds of a `DateTime` object in C#. Your existing comparison would then work with the higher accuracy.

```
List<Event> lstEvents = db.Events.Where(e => e.SystemDatetime.TotalMilliseconds <= eventItem.SystemDatetime.TotalMilliseconds).ToList();
```

Comment: Verify the query generated to confirm if the check is happening at the query level (in db) or within the C# application (memory)

Answer (score 0):

> DateTime comparisons only compare to the nearest second which isn't accurate enough.

This isn't true. It's depending on your data type of your DateTime column. Choose the datetime2 data type for more accuracy.

See the SQL below.

```
DECLARE @datetimes TABLE ([Column1] DATETIME2(7), [Column2] DATETIME2(7))

INSERT INTO
    @datetimes
VALUES
    ('2019-03-26 20:00:00.123', '2019-03-26 20:00:00.124')

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @datetimes
WHERE
    [Column1] <> [Column2]

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @datetimes
WHERE
    [Column1] = [Column2]
```